# importing mysql workbench 'create tables' to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I've been using MySQL Workbench to create my database, but have recently decided to export the structure to phpmyadmin.

Workbench has a feature where you can automatically generate the create scripts, and I get the following output when doing so:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;

USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`User`
-- -----------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`User` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`User` (
  `idUser` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Username` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `Password` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `DateJoined` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

My actual database is much more complex, but I'm using this as just an example. So now that I have the create statements, I try importing the file into phpmyadmin, which doesn't work, and also running the code in phpmyadmin itself. Both times, I get this error:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' to database 'mydb'
```

I initially thought the problem was that I am trying to execute sql without setting up a user. So, I set up a user in Workbench, and tried running the new create statements (which creates my user and the sufficient roles too), but I get the same error.

Finally, I tried creating the user in phpmyadmin and running the initial script, but I keep getting the same error.

Can someone please help?

EDIT: Above the actual error message, the following line is highlighted:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;**
```

I tried changing the charset but still get the error.

Comment: Do a `show grants for user@host` on the account you're using to run the queries manually. Most likely that account does not have create table privileges.

Comment: This is what I get: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myusername\_mydb`.* TO 'myusername'@'localhost'`

Comment: there's the problem. you're creating in a 'mydb' database, but have rights only on 'myusername_mydb'.